# Spawn and kill a process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to spawn a process in javascript, and kill it after some time (for testing purposes).

In the end, the process will be a infinite loop that I need to restart with different arguments at specified time, so I thought that spawning the process and killing it was the best way to do this.

My test code is:

```
var spawn=require('child_process').spawn
, child=null;

child=spawn('omxplayer', ['test.mp4'], function(){console.log('end');}, {timeout:6000});
console.log('Timeout');
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('kill');
    child.kill();
}, 1200);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('stdout:'+data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('stderr:'+data);
});

child.stdin.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('stdin:'+data);
});
```

The result is:

```
#~$ node test.js
Timeout
kill
```

But I still need to send ctrl+C to end the program. What am I missing?

On Raspbian, node 0.10.17, omxplayer is a binary (video player).

I tried:

- Added `chmod +x` to the app.
- Launched as root.
- Paused stdin of the child process. Using all terminate-related signal in the kill command.

I also launched a `ps` command while the app was running:

```
2145    bash
2174    node
2175    omxplayer
2176    omxplayer.bin
2177    ps
```

So omxplayer is a wrapper, who don t kill it's child process when it end, is there any way to get the pid of the wrapped process?

Still biting dust, tried this:

```
spawn('kill', ['-QUIT', '-$(ps opgid= '+child.pid+')']);
```

Which I thought would kill all children of omxplayer, I don t know if using spawn like that is wrong or if it's the code that doesn't work.

The last edit I made was the good answer, but had to be edited a bit.

I created a sh file (with execute right) like this:

```
PID=$1
PGID=$(ps opgid= "$PID")
kill -QUIT -"$PGID"
```

Which I start like this:

```
execF('kill.sh', [child.pid], function(){
    console.log('killed');
});
```

Instead of `child.kill`.

I'm not sure if it s the best way to do, nor if the code is clean, but it does work.

I'll accept any answer which make it in a cleaner way or, even better, without having to execute a file.

Comment: Raspberry Pi on Raspbian (not sure of the version) , node 0.10.2.
I ll try updating node.

Comment: Maybe it is something with the privileges. Try running your node script with root access.

Comment: Updated node to 0.10.17 and tried to run as root, none worked correctly.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/63) be the problem with omx. Try updating it.

Comment: I am guessing that the omxplayer executable is a wrapper to a process which outputs the video to screen and it does not close the video process it spawns.

Comment: The problem is not a black screen after the video played, but that even when I send a terminate signal, the video still play. I ll add that omxplayer is (almost) up to date, updated it one week ago, but added this patch: https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/16 To have seemless video transition.

Comment: Is there any way to get the pid of the video process so?

Comment: @user568109: Succeeded to launch a ps while omxplayer was running, I do get multiple instance, see edit.

Comment: what does execF mean?

Comment: @shuji: From memory, execFile, another method similar to spawn, and that should be near in the documentation

Comment: Please see @Superdrac answer which uses STDIN to send correct command to terminate omxplayer. It is cleaner and faster than all other approaches mentioned here.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Refer to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/U_O5wlwfq2c)

Once you start listening for data on stdin, node will wait for the input on stdin until it is told not to. When either user presses ctrl-d (meaning end of input) or the program calls stdin.pause(), node stops waiting on stdin.

A node program does not exit unless it has nothing to do or wait for. Whats happening is, it is waiting on stdin and therefore never exits.

Try changing your setTimeout callback to

```
console.log('kill');
child.stdin.pause();
child.kill();
```

I hope that should work.

Comment: Tried this too, and commented all "on data", I still need to wait the end of the video.

Comment: try child.kill('SIGKILL') and see if that works. child.kill() sends SIGHUP which just tell that the controlling terminal is closed or controlling process is closed. My assumption is SIGKILL would kill it for sure.

Comment: Tried SIGHUP, SIGTERM and SIGKILL, the message kill get printed, but the video still play.

Comment: Tried SIGKILL, SIGTERM, SIGABRT, SIGHUP, SIGINT and SIGQUIT, none of them did anything, even launched one after another.

Comment: When I try to spawn a child of some other command like pidgin, the code works just well. But it does not with omxplayer? Hmm.

Comment: user568109 answered this, omxplayer is just a wrapper for omxplayer.bin. So the spawn work, signal goes to omxplayer, but not to omxplayer.bin, which continue to execute.

Comment: I don t understand why someone downvoted all answer in here, I ve upvoted them back.

Comment: this fixes my issue with videos not having a duration and kills gracefully. Thanks! Perfect!

Comment: `Property 'pause' does not exist on type 'Writable'. ts(2339)
`

Comment: Please use `stdin.end()` instead of `stdin.pause()`.

Answer (score 61):

There is a really neat npm package called [`tree-kill`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill) which does this very easily and effectively. It kills the child process, *and* all child processes that child may have started.

```
var kill  = require('tree-kill');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var scriptArgs = ['myScript.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'youGetThePoint'];
var child = spawn('sh', scriptArgs);

// some code to identify when you want to kill the process. Could be
// a button on the client-side??
button.on('someEvent', function(){
    // where the killing happens
    kill(child.pid);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me and seems to be a great alternative.

Comment: This worked for me whilst `child.kill()` did not. Using NodeJS v14.15.1, Windows 10

Comment: I cannot upvote this enough - after wasting 5 hours this is the only solution that worked for me on Windows 7!

Comment: This was the only working solution for me. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if I want to execute a python script and then terminate it again with kill as described here. I mean the kill from `tree-kill`.

Comment: Thanks you, Michael Hall!!! This is the only thing that worked, I suffered for 2 hours

Answer (score 12):

I've had exactly the same issue as you with omxplayer and the solution in [this blog post](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn#killing-stopping-the-command) worked for me.

```
var psTree = require('ps-tree');

var kill = function (pid, signal, callback) {
    signal   = signal || 'SIGKILL';
    callback = callback || function () {};
    var killTree = true;
    if(killTree) {
        psTree(pid, function (err, children) {
            [pid].concat(
                children.map(function (p) {
                    return p.PID;
                })
            ).forEach(function (tpid) {
                try { process.kill(tpid, signal) }
                catch (ex) { }
            });
            callback();
        });
    } else {
        try { process.kill(pid, signal) }
        catch (ex) { }
        callback();
    }
};

// elsewhere in code
kill(child.pid);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just send the 'q' value in the stdin pipe ? It kill the omxplayer process.

Comment: can you explain this?

Comment: It's the natural behaviour of omxplayer. When you launch it in shell, the process is waiting for shortcuts like "q" which will close the program.

Comment: This is very clean solution and works for other programs too. f.stdin.write("q\n"); because some kind of enter is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You must specify the signal:

```
child.kill('SIGKILL')
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal

Answer (score 2):

In `node:16` I was required to `destroy()` (`pause()` i not enough) the `std` channels before sending `kill()`. Like this:

```
cmd.stdout.destroy();
cmd.stderr.destroy();
cmd.kill('SIGINT');
```

[See how `exec()` source code handles `kill()`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L770)

Answer (score 1):

You've spawned a child process which was successfully killed. However, your main thread is still executing, which is why you have to press Ctrl+C.

Comment: If it only was the main process that was still running, I would be happy, but the child process is obviously still running since the video still play until I send ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found how to do it without script:

```
exec('pkill omxplayer', function(err, stdout, stderr){
    if (stdout){console.log('stdout:'+stdout);}
    if (stderr){console.log('stderr:'+stderr);}
    if (err){throw err;}
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code in the latest lts node (v18).

```js
child.stdin.end();
child.stdout.destroy();
child.stderr.destroy();
child.kill();
```

It is better to destroy `stdout` and `stderr` pipes forcibly before killing process. Otherwise these pipes will still be available after kill during several miliseconds. Some open handler detectors may fail, for example `jest`:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  PIPEWRAP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `child_process.execFile()` method from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback).

> The child_process.execFile() function is similar to
> child_process.exec() except that it does not spawn a shell. Rather,
> the specified executable file is spawned directly as a new process
> making it slightly more efficient than child_process.exec().

It works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that might not exactly suit your use case is setting the `detached` option to `true` and ignoring stdin. Then, you can later kill your process using its PID.

```
const process = child_process.spawn(
  'omxplayer', ['test.mp4'],
  {
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
  }
);

setTimeout(() => {
  child_process.spawnSync(
    'kill', [process.pid.toString()]
  );
}, 1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Combining and clarifying answers from [@Superdrac + @Evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461355/18032774).*

If you're running something that has an exit command, just try using that command directly.

For example, most programs take `q` + `enter` to exit. So you can run:

```js
child.stdin.write("q\n");
```

and the process will interpret that the same way, allowing it to clean up itself.