# Node spawn process check for timout

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, spawn

I've spawned process which sometimes take to long to run, my question is there is a way to limit this process time ? for example kill this process after 3 min ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694684/spawn-and-kill-a-process-in-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `process.kill` in a timeout. But remember to cancel the timeout if the child finishes before it gets fired.

Take a look at this example:

This is `child.sh` that returns after 3 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3
echo DATA FROM CHILD
```

This is a Node program that spawns that child:

```
var seconds = process.argv[2] || 2;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('bash', ['child.sh'], {detached: true});
var stopped;
var timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Timeout');
  try {
    process.kill(-child.pid, 'SIGKILL');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot kill process');
  }
}, seconds*1000);
child.on('error', err => console.log('Error:', err));
child.on('exit', () => { console.log('Stopped'); clearTimeout(timeout); });
child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
```

By default it waits for 2 seconds, which is shorter than the child needs and the child will get killed, but you can add a different number of seconds as a command line argument:

```
node nodeprogram.js 10
```

to wait for 10 seconds which is enough for the child to finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Question: what's the difference between `process.kill(-self.child.pid, 'SIGKILL');` and `self.child.kill('SIGINT');`?

Answer (score 1):

From Node v14, spawn has a timeout value that you can specify using the options argument.  From the [Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), timeout  In milliseconds the maximum amount of time the process is allowed to run. Default: `undefined`

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

const someProcess = spawn('yes', 
  ['timeout in 10'], 
  {timeout: 5 * 1000} // 5 seconds
);

someProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString())
})

someProcess.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`Process exited with code ${code}`)
})
```