# Am I missing a timeout param in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I'm running an ffmpeg command like this:

`ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -report -timelimit 15 -timeout 10 -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i ${inputFile} -vframes 1 ${outputFile} -y`

This is running in an AWS Lambda function. My Lambda timeout is at 30 seconds. For some reason I am getting "Task timed out" messages still. I should note I log before and after the command, so I know it's timing out during this task.

**Update**

In terms of the entire lambda execution I do the following:

- Invoke a lambda to get an access token. This lambda makes on API request. It has a timeout of 5 seconds. The max time was 660MS for one request.
- Make another API request to verify data. The max time was 1.6 seconds.
- Run FFMPEG

`timelimit` is supposed to `Exit after ffmpeg has been running for duration seconds in CPU user time.`. Theoretically this shouldn't run more than 15 seconds then, plus maybe 2-3 more before the other requests.

`timeout` is probably superfluous here. There were a lot of definitions for it in the manual, but I think that was mainly waiting on input? Either way, I'd think `timelimit` would cover my bases.

**Update 2**

I checked my debug log and saw this:

```
Reading option '-timelimit' ... matched as option 'timelimit' (set max runtime in seconds) with argument '15'.
Reading option '-timeout' ... matched as AVOption 'timeout' with argument '10'.
```

Seems both options are supported by my build

**Update 2**

I have updated my code with a lot of logs. I definitively see the FFMPEG command as the last thing that executes, before stalling out for the 30 second timeout

**Update 3**
I can reproduce the behavior by pointing at a track instead of full manifest. I have set the command to this:

`ffmpeg -loglevel debug -timelimit 5 -timeout 5  -i 'https://streamprod-eastus-streamprodeastus-usea.streaming.media.azure.net/0c495135-95fa-48ec-a258-4ba40262e1be/23ab167b-9fec-439e-b447-d355ff5705df.ism/QualityLevels(200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)' -vframes 1 temp.jpg -y`

A few things here:

1. I typically point at the actual manifest (not the track), and things usually run much faster
2. I have lowered the `timelimit` and `timeout` to 5. Despite this, when i run a timer, the command runs for ~15 seconds every time. It outputs a bunch of errors, likely due to this being track rather than full manifest, and then spits out the desired image.

The full output is at https://gist.github.com/DaveStein/b3803f925d64dd96cd45ae9db5e5a4d0

Comment: Check log for whether timelimit was applied since it's not available on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Gyan. I updated my question. It seems I have these options applied.

Comment: That's not it. Search for `-timelimit not implemented on this OS`

Comment: @Gyan "not implemented" is nowhere in the log

Comment: Show the complete log from the `ffmpeg` command (without `-loglevel debug`).

Comment: @llogan done. added some more test info too

Comment: @llogan most of it are repeated lines you can glaze over ha but you can cmd+f and see that "not implemented" isn't there.

Comment: Ohhh sorry sorry. Default log level still outputs a lot @llogan https://gist.github.com/DaveStein/b3803f925d64dd96cd45ae9db5e5a4d0#gistcomment-3273624. At least when I hit the track

Comment: loglevel warning only shows messages about the timestamps

Comment: I'd try using a build of ffmpeg from the current git master branch before trying anything else. You'll only need one external component option: `--enable-gnutls`.

Comment: The timelimit option is documented as limiting the 'CPU user time.'  Perhaps whatever ffmpeg is taking a long time on is not CPU time but IO.

Comment: @craigts wouldn't that imply my `timeout` would do that since that's io?

Comment: timeout in the context you're using likely just refers to a 'connection timeout' not a timeout on the entire length of the transfer. It is totally plausible that your response starts before that timeout is hit, but that it takes a longer time to completely receive the response... especially if it is large.

Comment: @craigts I would expect the "length of the transfer" to fall under the cpu time bucket, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `timelimit` is supposed to `Exit after FFmpeg has been running for duration seconds in CPU user time`.

This is true but you can't use this timing metric to determine when FFmpeg should be forcefully exited during its operation (See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/48456)).

Best to watch the process from outside and force kill it by sending a `TERM` or `KILL` signal.

I'd recommend the `timeout` command that's part of the GNU coreutils.

Here's an example

```sh
timeout 14s -t 1s <FFMPEG COMMAND LINE>
```

This would ensure that the FFmpeg command execution runs for as long as 14 seconds and forces it to be killed (`SIGKILL`) one second after that in case it didn't quit with the `SIGTERM` signal.

You can check the man pages for the [timeout](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command.

Comment: Interesting solution! I will give it a shot.

Comment: just having trouble since I use Node child_process.spawn so figuring how to pass that in properly

Comment: Thanks for thinking outside the box here and just killing it from outside `ffmpeg`. I will award this as the answer. My actual solution (as I run this via lambda) was more akin to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612602/node-spawn-process-check-for-timout

Answer (score 1):

you can try these things:

1. increase the timeout-limit of your lambda function.
2. increase the memory allocation to your lambda function. It speeds up your lambda function.
3. If you still gets timeout than check RequestTimeout and ConnectionTimeout of your lambda function.

Comment: I can't increase timeout on the lambda because it's time sensitive. I will try bumping memory up though and see if that improves things. If that does, you are winner :)

Comment: Fingers crossed . Keep that in mind this would may increase per execution cost. Lambda execution cost is proportional to memory allocated to function and execution time.

Comment: Bumped it once. Bumping it a little more to see if there's a change. So far no good.

Comment: No dice. 17 fails in 24 hours.

Comment: you need to find balance between memory allocated and timeout timing. Use multi-threading and move some functionality to async to make your function fast.