# Node.js ChildProcess#kill() does not kill Node.js processes created by npm.cmd on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, cmd, child-process

I am trying to kill child processes created by command `npm.cmd` (spawned using Node.js API) on Windows.

It executes something like `npm.cmd run build`. Using `process.kill()` seems to be able to end the `npm.cmd` command successfully, but not the Node.js processes created by the npm command.

```
let cp = spawn('npm.cmd', ['run', 'build']);

cp.on('exit', code => {
  // It will log after 5 seconds.
  // But Node.js process created by `npm run build` will not end.
  console.log(`Exited with code ${code}.`);
});

setTimeout(() => cp.kill(), 5000);
```

I tried to replace `process.kill()` to something like `spawn('taskkill', ['/f', '/t', '/pid', process.pid])` and it worked well. How can I achieve the same thing using Node.js API?

Comment: maybe this thread on stackoverflow will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694940/6006584, it is basically suggest you pause the stdin just before sending the kill command