# Executed a java process in nodejs but how to stop it

Tags: java, node.js, command-line, child-process

I want to make a admin dashboard where I can start my simulation by a click to /start route
and stop it by a click to /stop route now I am able to start the simulation but not stop it so how can I do it.
or what cmd to run so that it can find the java process and stop it?

```
router.get('/start',function(req, res, next){
        // res.send("start");
        var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
        var child = exec('cd ../Simulation && java -jar Simulation.jar',function (error, stdout, stderr){ 
        console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
        res.render('user/admin',{
                title:'Account'
            });
        if(error !== null){
            console.log("Error -> "+error); 
            res.send("error occured");
            } 
        });
        res.render('user/admin',{
            title:'Account'
        });
        module.exports = child; 
    });

    router.get('/stop',function(req, res, next){
        var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
        var child = exec('',function (error, stdout, stderr){ 
        console.log('Output -> ' + stdout); 
        if(error !== null){
            console.log("Error -> "+error); } 
        });
        module.exports = child;     
    });
```

I left this cmd empty

```
var child = exec('',function (error, stdout, stderr){
```

Comment: I would guess this is probably platform-dependent. Are you using Linux? In which case, it looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694684/spawn-and-kill-a-process-in-node-js)

Comment: I am using Linux on aws server and it is different because in that question child is stored globally but because I want this in routes so but if I close my browser and then try to go to /stop it gives child is undefined and when I define it doesn't kill it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill()` method:

```
exec.kill()
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal