# console kill command does not work on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

Hello I have this command on my Nodejs application which finds a process with the trim name and kills it.

```
let killTrim = () => {
  console.log('kill "$(pgrep -f ' + trimName + '.mp4)"')
  cmd.run('kill "$(pgrep -f ' + trimName + '.mp4)"')
  trimName = null
}
```

this works perfectly fine on localhost on my computer but won't work on my server (ubuntu 16.04). The console log is outputted but the cmd.run command doesn't run on the server. When I manually put in 'kill "$(pgrep -f moo.mp4)"' on the server it will run and kill the process.

I've done some research on the issue but I haven't been able to find anything issues similar to this.

Comment: check for permission in server

Comment: Are you sure your node app and the process are running under the same user?

Comment: Could you please replace `cmd.run(...)` with `cmd.get(...,(err,data,std)=>{console.log('err',err);console.log('out',data);console.log('stderr',std);}`)
and show result?

Comment: @VasylMoskalov Here are the results https://pastebin.com/xSZWgh04

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it

Comment: @Ricky, can you check the answer I posted and provide feedback?

Comment: Something to look into, found in the logs.  `/bin/sh: 1: kill: Illegal number: 10579`. Find the reason for that & your issue will be resolved.

Comment: @Ricky, `pgrep` finds all the pids associated with a process. So yours is returning several associated `pids`. On your local terminal try running `pgrep -if chrome` to see the same this working on chrome. In order to kill the Chrome process, you need to kill the process that spawns all the child processes. This is mentioned properly in Tharun's answer. Try running `kill "$(pgrep -if chrome)"` and then try `pgrep -i chrome | xargs kill` to understand what's going on. Make sure that on the server you have the rights to kill the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked on your pastebin. Looks like that `pgrep -f ...` return more than one pid. So try this one:

```
cmd.run('for a in $(pgrep -f '+trimName+'.mp4); do kill $a; done');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work and the process still was not killed

Comment: Sorry for the belated response, I lost my job. This solution worked, the problem was as you stated, multiple pid

Answer (score 3):

I would use something simple like below

```
cmd = require('node-cmd');
cmd.get('pgrep -f node | xargs kill', (err, data, stderr) => {
  console.log(err, data, stderr);
});
```

It will work even when you have multiple processes running

[image: Processes terminated]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that your node application does not have enough permission to kill the process. You can try the following:

```
sudo node app.js
```

Comment: Actually tried that, also ran it on sudo pm2 start app.js still doesn't go through

Comment: You can try to create bash script where you put `kill "$(pgrep -f $1)"`  like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18694684/4731371) and then execute it from nodejs

Comment: The problem with that is the name of the process is dynamic

Comment: You can [pass arguments to bash script](https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571) and get them in script with `$@`.