# How to kill child process/close Chrome?

Tags: node.js, child-process

Let's start with the code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const ChildProc = require('child_process');

const chrome = ChildProc.spawn('/usr/bin/google-chrome',['--incognito',`--app=data:text/html,<p>Hello World</p>`],{detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
chrome.unref();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('killing');
  chrome.kill();
}, 2500); // pretend we did some stuff, and now we're done with chrome.
```

My Chrome window is opening, but I can't get it to close programatically. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: You might have to capture the actual process id from the console and send a specific process id to the kill command

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694684/spawn-and-kill-a-process-in-node-js) to see if it can help you

Comment: @Sterling Archer: 'tree-kill' does not work, child.stdin.pause() does not work (I've already ignored stdio),  psTree does not work...

Comment: Perhaps it's a feature in chrome to stop programs from shutting it down? Might have to look into chromium to see if it allows nodejs to send it SIGKILL signals

Comment: Is it working without `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: @TGrif Hard to tell. The window never opens.

Answer (score 0):

I found [chrome-launcher](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/src/chrome-launcher.ts) and looked at the source code. Apparently the trick to making this work is `--user-data-dir=/tmp/lighthouse.6ppUDxi` command-line flag.

e.g., this works:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const ChildProc = require('child_process');

function makeUnixTmpDir() {
  return ChildProc.execSync('mktemp -d -t lighthouse.XXXXXXX').toString().trim();
}

const chrome = ChildProc.spawn('/usr/bin/google-chrome',[
  '--disable-translate',
  '--disable-extensions',
  '--disable-background-networking',
  '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update',
  '--disable-sync',
  '--metrics-recording-only',
  '--disable-default-apps',
  '--mute-audio',
  '--no-first-run',
  '--user-data-dir='+makeUnixTmpDir(),
  'https://google.com',
],{detached: true, stdio: 'ignore'});
// chrome.unref();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('killing');
  chrome.kill();
}, 5000); // pretend we did some stuff, and now we're done with chrome.
```

It probably has something to do with how Chrome merges processes, but I guess it won't do that if the window is using it's own user profile.

Comment: How these could be relevant? I even tried it but there were no effects.

Comment: @AliTou Dunno man. I put my best guess in the last sentence.