# Completely clear spawn

Tags: node.js, cmd

Is it necessary to `null` the spawn after `pause` and `kill`?

```
let child = spawn(cmd_str);
child.on('exit', code => {
    child.stdin.pause();
    child.kill();

    child = null;
});
```

I don't want my module to have a chance to take the extra resources from the system after doing it's job.

Comment: probably this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694684/spawn-and-kill-a-process-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary.

*JavaScript* has a garbage collector fonctionnality that takes care of cleaning memory for variable that are not used any more.

One thing you could do instead to be sure the subprocess has been killed with success is to listen to the `close` or `error` event, as shown in the example from the NodeJS [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal).

You could also track the process by its PID to make sure it is not alive anymore.

Note that I don't fully understand why you need to kill your process on `exit`, you should maybe focus on a clean exit of the subprocess program.