# How can I cancel a bash command/script from my Electron app with Node's child_process?

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, spawn

I'm running an electron app with Wraith. I'm using node's `child_process` and it works really well except for cancelling a bash script/command.
I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me online.

I want to run a command that would essentially operate similar to `ctrl + c` but from my Electron app.

I've stripped down my code to make it easier to read:

My `index.js` file

```
var electron = require("electron");
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;
var shell = require('electron').shell;
var remote = require('electron').remote
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runScript(index) {

    var directory = __dirname + '/src/bash/';

    // Works as expected
    var vrt = spawn('/bin/sh',
        [directory + task, arg1, arg2]);

    vrt.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
    });

    //This doesn't work
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("should close")
        vrt.kill();
    }, 1000)
}
```

The console.log confirms that the script continues running even though `vrt.kill()` has been called.

This method has popped up several times during my search for answers. Does anyone have an idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, All

Your help is much appreciated

Moe

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var electron = require("electron");
var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;
var shell = require('electron').shell;
var remote = require('electron').remote
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function runScript(index) {

    var directory = __dirname + '/src/bash/';

    // Works as expected
    var vrt = spawn('/bin/sh',
        [directory + task, arg1, arg2]);

vrt.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
        vrt.stdin.pause();
        vrt.kill();
    });

}
```

Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18694940/12167785

Comment: @Moe-Joe is it solving the problem?

Comment: @Sudhaker No luck. The console logs the data but the process doesn't stop, it just continues as normal.